# Let $f\colon G\to L$ be a homomorphism of groups. Prove that if $|G|=20$ and $|L|=17$, then $f(g) = e_L$ (identity of $L$), for every $g\in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that there is a theorem that states that If $(G, *)$ and $(H, •)$ are groups, $e_G$ (identity of $G$) and $e_H$ (identity of $H$). Let $f: G\to H$ be a  homomorphism. Then

1. $f(e_G) = e_H$.

I don't know how to use this, or begin my proof or should I use kernel for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Note $f(G) < L$. By the first isomorphism theorem $f(G) \approx G/\ker f$. Therefore $|f(G)| = |G|/\lvert\ker f\rvert$. But the order of $f(G)$ divides the order of $L$ which only happens when $|G|=\lvert\ker f\rvert$ which implies $f$ is the trivial map as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:G \to H$ be a homomorphism of groups, where $|G|=20$ and $|L|=17$.
Let $g \in G$ be any element, then the order of $g$ divides $20$, thus $g^{20}=e_G$, so after applying $f$ we get $f(g)^{20}=f(e_G)=e_L$, so the order of $f(g)$ divides $20$ as well. Now as $f(g)$ is an element of $L$, the order of $f(g)$ also divides $17$. As $17$ and $20$ are coprime, the order of $f(g)$ must be one, i.e. $f(g)=e_L$.